# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex'): jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am getting error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')` when i use stateSave in jquery datatable in following way:

```js
stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
    $.get("/api/settings/datatable-state", {
        table_id: $(this).attr("id")
    }, function (result) {
        if (result.status == "success") {
            try {
                callback(JSON.parse(result.data.table_state));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    });
    return {};
}
```

.

I tried to debug it by usinng `stateLoadCallback` in the following way, it works:

```js
stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")));
},
```

But if i do the following, i am getting error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')`:

```js
stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
    callback(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id"))));
    return {};
},
```

I created the table in html in following way:

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"
    id="stock_out_product_customer_wise_sales_table" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

and called the datatable like following:

```js
window.improved_sales_payment_entry_table = $("#improved-sales-form #payment-table").DataTable({
    bInfo: false,
    ordering: false,
    destroy: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Method",
            data: "method_name"
        },
        ...
    ]
});
```